# Unable to get proper speed between locations due to wrong GPS location

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am trying to find speed between two locations but found that **GPS location** is inaccurate. I am at the same location and it keeps on providing different location For e.g It provides me location that's far about 200KM from me.

```
public class LocationTracker extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, SensorEventListener {

// LogCat tag
private static final String TAG = "LocationTracker";

private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;
private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 2000; // 2 sec
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 2; // 2 meters
private Context context;
private SharedPreferences sp;

// Location updates intervals in sec
private Location mLastLocation;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private double latitude, longitude;
private boolean firstLocation = false;

private float speed;


public LocationTracker(Context ctx, boolean firstLocation) {

    context = ctx;

    sp = context.getSharedPreferences(Utility.SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);

    this.firstLocation = firstLocation;

    // First we need to check availability of play services
    if (checkPlayServices()) {

        createLocationRequest();
        buildGoogleApiClient();


        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

/**
 * Creating google api client object
 */
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

/**
 * Method to verify google play services on the device
 */
private boolean checkPlayServices() {

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);

    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
            Utility.showLog(TAG, "Something went wrong with error code :" + resultCode);
        else
            Utility.showLog(TAG,
                    "This device is not supported.");

        // stopLocationUpdates();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


/**
 * Creating location request object
 */
protected void createLocationRequest() {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT); // 10 meters

}

/**
 * Starting the location updates
 */
public void startLocationUpdates() {

    Utility.showLog(TAG, "Starting Location Updates");

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}

/**
 * Stopping location updates
 */
public void stopLocationUpdates() {

    Utility.showLog(TAG, "Stopping Location Updates");


    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    }
    stopSelf();

}


/**
 * Function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude() {

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 */
public double getLongitude() {

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Utility.showLog(TAG, "Google API Connected");


    // Once connected with google api, get the location
    updateLocation();
    startLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    // Assign the new location
    mLastLocation = location;
    updateLocation();

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

/**
 * Method to display the location on UI
 */
private void updateLocation() {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {

        if (firstLocation) {

            sp.edit().putString("last_latitude", String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude())).commit();
            sp.edit().putString("last_longitude", String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude())).commit();
            sp.edit().putLong("last_location_time", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();

            firstLocation = false;

            Utility.showLog(TAG, "Last Latitude : " + mLastLocation.getLatitude());
            Utility.showLog(TAG, "Last Longitude : " + mLastLocation.getLongitude());

        }

        latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        heading = mLastLocation.getBearing();
        altitude = mLastLocation.getAltitude();

        Utility.showLog(TAG, " Latitude : " + latitude);
        Utility.showLog(TAG, " Longitude : " + longitude);

        Utility.showLog(TAG, "Heading :" + heading);
        Utility.showLog(TAG, "Altitude :" + altitude);


    } else
        Utility.showLog(TAG, "Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Utility.showLog(TAG, "Location Tracker Stopped");
}

/**
 * Function to get Speed
 */

public double getSpeed() {


    double previousLatitude = Double.parseDouble(sp.getString("last_latitude", "0.0"));
    double previousLongitude = Double.parseDouble(sp.getString("last_longitude", "0.0"));

    Utility.showLog(TAG, "Old Latitude :" + previousLatitude);
    Utility.showLog(TAG, "Old Longitude :" + previousLongitude);

    Utility.showLog(TAG, "New Latitude :" + latitude);
    Utility.showLog(TAG, "New Longitude :" + longitude);

    Location sourceLocation = new Location("A");
    sourceLocation.setLatitude(previousLatitude);
    sourceLocation.setLongitude(previousLongitude);

    Location destinationLocation = new Location("B");
    destinationLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
    destinationLocation.setLongitude(longitude);


    double distance = sourceLocation.distanceTo(destinationLocation);

    Utility.showLog(TAG, "Distance =" + distance);

    float differenceInTime = (float) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - sp.getLong("last_location_time", 0)) / 1000);

    Utility.showLog(TAG, "Current Time :" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    Utility.showLog(TAG, "Last Time :" + sp.getLong("last_location_time", 0));

    Utility.showLog(TAG, "Difference in Time " + differenceInTime);

    double mps = distance / differenceInTime;
    double kph = (mps * 3600) / 1000;

    return kph;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please check the accuracy of the location obtained. And if the accuracy value is high(high depends on your decision), then ignore it.

You can get Accuracy using

```
location.getAccuracy();
```

At times when you are inside a building, there are chances that your location accuracy will be around 2km sometimes. You can ignore in this case. This accuracy depends on the number of satellites that are providing the result.

Comment: I am getting the difference of more than 100KM

Comment: At times, difference is 0 KM. Why so much difference??

Comment: When you see these differences does the GPS have clear line of site of the sky?

Comment: @droid_dev : the difference is as i said based on the gps satellites that are available. so when you are inside building, you may for example get data which is from 3 satellites and hence less accurate. but when you are in open sky, you may get good result as the result will be obtained from lets say 9 satellites.

Comment: Another thing to note is, if you getting the location from network then it will be less accurate as compare to data obtained from gps. Also if the difference you are getting more than 100km, then surely it should be ignored and wait for more accurate location

Comment: Yesterday i had a driving test and found that locations were inaccurate but with GPS accuracy locations were totally wrong. Something is really wrong